# How can I get the count of windows in the current workspace?

Tags: xmonad

Within the context of `X ()`, how can I get a count of the current windows in the workspace?

I know how to get the count from `WindowSet` and there is a function of `windows :: (WindowSet -> WindowSet) -> X ()`. However I'd like to actually return a value so it would have to be something like `(WindowSet -> WindowSet) -> X Int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out by looking at the implementation of `windows`.

```
import XMonad (windows, X, WindowSet, XState(XState, windowset))
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import Control.Monad.State


getWindowState :: X (WindowSet)
getWindowState = do
    XState { windowset = old } <- get
    return $ old
```

And then within the context of `X ()`:

```
ws <- getWindowState >>= (return . W.stack . W.workspace . W.current)
let ws' = maybe 0 (length . W.integrate) ws
```

Answer (score 3):

Shorter version of Chris answer without additional function. 
If `ws'` represents length of windows list like in his answer, then:
`ws' <- length . W.integrate' . W.stack . W.workspace . W.current . windowset <$> get`

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter variants thanks to W.index:

```
winCount = length . W.index . windowset <$> get
winCount = gets (windowset) >>= return . length . W.index
winCount = gets (W.index . windowset) >>= return . length
```